# Faction War Assets Gained

Tags: for-honor

After each match, you get a certain amount of "Faction War Assets".  How is the amount you receive after each match calculated?  The only thing I could find on [Ubisoft's website](https://forhonor.ubisoft.com/game/en-US/news-community/152-283133-16/how-to-master-the-faction-war-for-honor-tips) just vaguely said something like 'doing better gets you more points'.  Any more details on that?  Specifically,

- Is it just win/loss, or does your personal score and/or kdr matter?
- Does match time matter?  If so, what is better, longer matches or shorter?  Does it depend on if your team won?
- Does the type of match matter?  There is a "Front War Bonus" that gives you 20% - I assume that means that if you apply your assets to a sector that is of the match type you just played, you get that bonus, correct?
- Is there any kind of handicapping for one faction having more active players during the last war?
- Are there any bonuses for playing with friends?
- Do all factions start out even? **No, some factions start with a lead when a new round starts, but I'm not sure how that is determined.**

Any insight into any of these questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order:
think it is a little bit of everything.

As far as I can tell, match time doesn't matter.

Each match type gives a differant amount. Duels and brawls give the least, fairly certain dominion gives the most.

Yes, the front war bonus is applied if you put troops in the same area of the map you are currently playing in.

The amount of troops you get is adjusted for your faction size. Smaller faction gets more troops per match.

I think if you have friends of the same faction with you in a party, it offers a small boost to troops.. Can't confirm this. I do know that if you have multiple champions In a party you all get a boost to xp.

In addition, you also get a troop boost if your defending or attacking territory deep inside your area of the map, like near the stronghold.